# What am I doing wrong - trigonometry and pythag question

Tags: trigonometry

This is the question. The answers I got is extremely close to the answers. It seems really easy so I am wondering if the answer in the book is wrong. Please let me know what you guys get. Thank you.

[image: RockClimbingGym]

$\underline{\text{My Attempt}}$:

$\bf{\text{part a.}}$

So since this is a rectangle, to find distance $AB$ I used the fact the width is 12m and 4.44-1 = 3.44m

So then creating a right angle triangle where the hypotenuse is distance $AB$ : 12^2 + 3.44^2= 12.483^2

To find the distance from B to the top-center of the wall using the same idea:
6^2 +(20-4.44)^=16.6767^2

So adding the two together :
12.483+16.6767=29.16.

However, the answer given in the book is 29.47m.

$\bf{\text{part b.}}$

I don't really know how to do this. However, I tried:

Since we have the distance from $B$ to the top of the wall (16.6767) we can create another right angle triangle which projects outwards from the wall where the hypotenuse is from point $B$ to 0.5m away from the wall. (Blue solid line)

So then we have 16.6767^2 +0.5^2= 16.6842^2.

Then using trig:

$$\tan\left(\theta\right) =\dfrac{12.483}{16.6842} \quad\rightarrow\quad \theta = 36.8^o$$

The answer given in the book is $39.69^o$.

I do not like to think the book is wrong so I am sure my method is wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).